# GetStream - Rate limit

Tags: getstream-io

We are currently using the free plan and we frequently we receive a response code 429 with an explanation "The request hit the rate limits for your app". As it seems the app hits one of the time based rate limits as described here: https://getstream.io/docs/#rate-limiting. Is it possible that we can see which exact limit we are reaching?

Comment: Please check the response headers of your rate limited requests. you will find useful information about the limits (X-RateLimit-Limit,X-RateLimit-Remaining,X-RateLimit-Reset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll receive an email to the address associated with the account with the detail of which endpoint was limited and how many calls were attempted in the associated period of time. Please reach out through our site form if you need more help.